# why my unit test for my rest controller method with mock doesn't work?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I try to make a dummy test of a method in my controller but doesn't work , i have a null pointer exception and i would like to know why it doesn't work, i precise that's my first time when i make this kind of tests.

This is my rest controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

 @Secured(value = "ROLE_ADMIN")
    @GetMapping("/roles")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Role>> getRoles(){

        return new  ResponseEntity(userService.getRoles(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

This my controller test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = AdminController.class, secure = false)

public class AdminControllerTest {


    private MockMvc mvc;


    @MockBean
    UserService userService;
 @Test
    public void getRoles() throws Exception{

        Role role=new Role("Admin");

        List<Role> roles=Arrays.asList(role);
        given(userService.getRoles()).willReturn(roles);
        mvc.perform(get("/api/roles")).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

When i run the test for this method a i have this kind of error :

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Could you please include stack trace not as image. I could not see your error image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should work. I think you missed `@Autowired` annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(value = AdminController.class, secure = false)
    public class AdminControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mvc;
        @MockBean
        UserService userService;
        @Test
        public void getRoles() throws Exception{

            Role role=new Role("Admin");

            List<Role> roles=Arrays.asList(role);
            given(userService.getRoles()).willReturn(roles);
            mvc.perform(get("/api/roles")).andExpect(status().isOk());

        }
    }
```